# Conditionally get the sum from a list

Tags: c#, linq, list

I have a class PropertyDetails:

```
public class PropertyDetails 
{      
    public int Sequence { get; set; } 

    public int Length { get; set; }   

    public string Type { get; set; } 
}
```

I am creating a list of PropertyDetails as

```
List<PropertyDetails> propertyDetailsList = new List<PropertyDetails>();
```

I want the sum of `Length` from the list where `PropertyDetails.Sequence` < sumValue=4

Linq solutions are welcome.

Comment: What does `PropertyDetails.Sequence < sumValue=4` mean?

Answer (score 16):

Sum of the Lengths where the Sequence is less than 4:

```
 var result = propertyDetailsList.Where(d => d.Sequence < 4)
                                 .Sum(d => d.Length);
```

Answer (score 7):

You can use the `Sum` extension method from linq. First you filter out those items that don't fulfill your condition using `Where`. Then you either use `Select(pd=>pd.Length).Sum()`, or the overload that maps the item from PropertyDetail to Length using the function passed to `Sum()`.

```
const int sumValue = 4;
propertyDetailsList
    .Where(pd=>pd.Sequence < sumValue)
    .Sum(pd=>pd.Length);
```

Answer (score 6):

```
int sumLength = propertyDetailsList.Where(p => p.Sequence < 4).Sum(p => p.Length);
```

Comment: ? Answered within 4mins 40 seconds of OP's post?

Comment: @nonnb dtb has already answerd that, other this could have been accepted.

Answer (score 3):

```
var list = from p in propertyDetailsList
   where p.Sequence < 4
   select p.Length;

Console.WriteLine("sum is {0}", list .Sum())
```

Comment: You need to indent your code, else it won't be displayed correctly. Select the code and hit Ctrl+K

Answer (score 0):

```
decimal? dRemainingBalance = dataModal.Where(x => x.StatusID == 100 || x.StatusID == 200 || x.StatusID == 300).Sum(x => Convert.ToDecimal(x.RemainingBalance));
```

[image]